# Store images and videos category wise and fetch them in json format

Tags: media-library, json

I am try to store images and videos category wise , I used "Enhanced Media Library" plugin to categorize media. Now I have to fetch media category wise and show in json format. I am using JSON API, however dont know what method and parameters to use. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Some how able to get all the images from media library. This is very close.

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image ) {
    $images[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```